# automate script copy and delete batch window 8?

Tags: batch-file

I have a project in my school and I want to copy folder using batch files, but I don't a3ref kif ?

please, how can I copy files using .bat ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `xcopy` for copying the files and `rmdir` for deleting files.

Answer (score 0):

Copy a file:

echo F| XCOPY C:\utils\MyFile.txt D:\Backup\CopyFile.txt

Copy a folder:

XCOPY C:\utils D:\Backup\utils /i

Copy a folder including all subfolders.

XCOPY C:\utils* D:\Backup\utils /s /i